# iterating through a div component without having the .mouseover() function repeated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Goodday all,

Please i need help.....

I have this html(ejs) view and i am dynamically rendering it with data i get...
it is working ok as a single div. when i have more than one data and iterate through it,the other part of the component works as expected by creating the number of divs it needs to display data. Now the div supposed to show on mouseover()popups on every div when i just touch the first div. 
I can't seem to find the logic error...
(I am using express and node js)
please help

thank you in advance

below is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>TODO supply a title</title>
<link href="/css/index.css" rel="Stylesheet"/>
<script src="/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="container">

<form action="/models/top100.js">

<div  id="bodydiv" > <div id="leftdiv" > 
<% for (let a=0; a < 2; a++){%>
<ul class="innerdiv" >
<li class="arrowdiv">
<img src='images/orangearrow.png'  alt="" id='imgdiv' class='imgdiv' data-
src='images/orangearrow.png' data-hover='images/whitearrow.png'/>

<ul class="popup" id="popup">
<li class="col1">1
</li><li class="col2">2
</li><li class="col3">  3
</li><li class="col4">
<img src="images/blackarrow.png"  alt="" class="col4"/>
</li>
</ul>

</li><li class="artdiv">
<ul>
<li class="contentdiv"><%= [a] %></li>
<li class="rcontentdiv">image</li>
<li class="ccontentdiv"><%= [a]%></li>
</ul></li>
</ul>
<%} %>
</div>

</div> 

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

the jquery function for mouseover

```
<script>
$(".imgdiv").mouseover(function () {
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).data("hover"));
    $( ".popup" ).toggle('slow');
}).mouseout(function () {
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).data("src"));
    $( ".popup" ).hide();
});
</script>
```

the cSS

```
*
{
margin: 0px;
}
#admin
{
margin-top: 100px;
font-family:"Times New Roman";
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: bold;
margin-left: 400px;
line-height: 30px;
}
.comp1
{
margin-left: 20px;
}

.comp2
{
margin-left: 30px;
}
.comp3
{
margin-left: 25px;
}

#login
{
margin-top: 100px;
font-family:"Times New Roman";
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: bold;
margin-left: 400px;
line-height: 20px;
}
.comp
{
align-content: center;
font-weight: bold;
background-color: black;
color: white;
width: 80px;
height: 25px;
margin-left:100px;
margin-top: 10px;
}
.comp5
{
align-content: center;
font-weight: bold;
background-color: black;
color: white;
width: 80px;
height: 25px;
margin-left:20px;
margin-top: 10px;
}
.comp6
{
align-content: center;
font-weight: bold;
background-color: black;
color: white;
width: 80px;
height: 25px;
margin-left:10px;
margin-top: 10px;
}
body
{
background-color:  white;  
font-family: "Intro-Inline";

}

/* @font-face kit by Fonts2u (http://www.fonts2u.com) */
@font-face {font-family:"Intro-Inline";src:url("mywebfonts/Intro_Inline.eot?") 
        format("eot"),url("mywebfonts/Intro_Inline.woff") format("woff"),
                url("mywebfonts/Intro_Inline.ttf")
        format("truetype"),url("mywebfonts/Intro_Inline.svg#Intro-Inline") format("svg");
    }

/*wrapper for the main container*/
#wrapper
{
margin: auto;
}
/*all divs under this container to be maintained in aspect*/
#container
{
position:absolute;
margin:0px auto;
}

/*wrapper for navigation divs and <a>*/    
.wrapper1{
width:780px;
height:55px;
margin-left: 15vh;
margin-top:30px;
text-align:  left;
display: inline-block;
border-width: 4px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: orange;
position: static;
}
/*div for charts news music*/
.div1
{
width:380px;
height:50px;
font-size: 25px;
font-weight:  lighter;
color: white;
float:left;
padding:0px 10px 0px 10px;
text-align:  left;
border-width: 4px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: red;
}
/*div for facebook twitter instagram and search*/
.searchdiv
{
width:140px;
height:50px;
float:left; 
/*  padding:0px;
margin:0px;
line-height: 0px;
font-size: 0px;
margin-left:0px;*/
white-space:  nowrap;
display:inline-block;
border-style: solid;
border-color:yellow;
border-width:4px;
}
.menudiv{

float:right;
padding-right: 50px;
margin-left: 30px;}
/*searchboxdiv*/
.searchboxdiv
{
width:120px;
height:40px;
white-space:nowrap;
font-size:0px;
display:inline-block;
align-items:  center;
float:left ;
padding:0px 30px 0px 0px;
border-width: 4px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: chartreuse;
}
.searchicon
{
width:20px;
margin:0 auto;
padding:0px;
/* float:left;*/

}
/*div for menu*/
.divmenu
{
width:50px;
height:50px;
float:left;
margin-left: 0vh;
border-width: 4px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: green;
}
/*navigation*/
nav
{
position:fixed;
width:100%;
height:120px;
/*   background-color: rgba ();*/
background-color: black;
text-align: right;
vertical-align:  middle;
color:white;

/*  padding:5px 0px 20px 0px;*/
z-index: 99;

}
nav a
{
color: white;
/*font-weight: bold;*/
font-size: 18px;
text-decoration: none;
margin-left: 30px;
line-height: 150px;
/*  padding:0px 10px 0px 10px;*/

}
/*div for logo*/
.logodiv
{
float:left;
color:white;
width: 80px;
/*  margin-left: 5vh;*/
margin-top:5vh;
margin-bottom:2vh;
font-weight: bolder;
font-size: 50px;
z-index:10;
position: fixed; /*newly added*/
left: 30vh; /*newly added*/
/* padding:0vh 100vh 0vh 0vh;*/
vertical-align: middle;
}

/*css for the icons on nav*/
.icons
{
width:20px;
height:20px;

}
/*css for the body*/
#bodydiv
{
margin:0 auto;
padding:0px;
}

#leftdiv
{
margin-top:30vh;
margin-left:30vh;
width:80vh;
height:75vh;
float:left;
margin-bottom: 2vh;
/*    border-width: 4px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: yellow;*/
}


#rightdiv
{
margin-top: 30vh;
float:right;
margin-left: 130vh;
position: fixed;
width:40vh;
height:75vh;
/*   border-width: 4px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: yellow;*/
}
.topdiv
{

width:35vh;
height:35vh;
text-align:  center;
vertical-align:  middle;
background-color:  gray;
/*   border-width: 4px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: red;*/
color:black;
word-wrap: true; 
font-size: 26;
float: right;
min-width: 25%;
}
.innertopdiv
{

width:35vh;
height:25vh;
text-align:  center;
vertical-align:  middle;

margin-top: 5vh;
background-color:  rgb(58, 14, 14);
/*   border-width: 4px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: red;*/
color:white;
word-wrap: true; 
font-size: 26;
float: right;
min-width: 25%;
}
.bottomdiv
{

line-height:  100px;
text-align:  center;
width:35vh;
height:30vh;
margin-top:5vh;
background-color:  black;
/*  border-width: 4px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: orange;*/
float: right;
min-width: 25%;
}
/*div to multiply
tr{

}*/
.innerdiv
{


width:80vh;
height:20vh;
padding:0px;
list-style-type: none;
margin:0px;
float:left;
position:relative;
background-color: gray;
border-width: 1px;
border-style: solid;
display:inline-block;
border-color: black;
text-decoration: none;
list-style-type: none;
}
.artdiv
{


width:71vh;
height:19.5vh;
padding:0px;
top:2px;
list-style-type: none;
text-decoration: none;

margin:0px;
right: 5px;
float:right;
position:relative;
background-color: gray;
display:table-cell;
/*      border-width: 1px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: black;
text-decoration: none;
list-style-type: none;*/
}
.artdiv:hover
{


width:71vh;
height:19.5vh;
padding:0px;
top:2px;
list-style-type: none;
text-decoration: none;

margin:0px;
right: 5px;
float:right;
position:relative;
background-color: #909090;
display:table-cell;
}

.innertop
{
z-index: 99;
position:  fixed;
width:34.5vh;
height:5vh;
background-color: black;
color: white;
font-stretch:  extra-expanded;
font-size:25px;
line-height: 30px;
border-width: 1px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: black;

}
.innerbottom
{
z-index: 99;
position:  fixed;
width:35vh;
height:5vh;
background-color:gray;
color: white;
font-stretch:  extra-expanded;
font-size:28px;
line-height: 30px;

}
/*div working for contents of music*/
.contentdiv
{
width:23.3vh;
height:15vh;
list-style: none;
vertical-align:  middle;
top:20px;
right: 30px;
/*margin-top:2vh;*/
text-decoration: none;
display:table-cell;
margin-right:5vh;
background-color:  orange;
text-align:  center;
text-decoration: none;
}
.arrowdiv
{
width:8vh;
height:19.9vh;
line-height:  1vh;
margin-right:1vh;
vertical-align:  middle;
background-color: black;
display:inline-block;
text-decoration: none;
}
.arrowdiv:hover
{
width:8vh;
height:19.9vh;
line-height:  1vh;
margin-right:1vh;
vertical-align:  middle;
background-color: #282828 ;
display:inline-block;
text-decoration: none;
}

.ccontentdiv
{
width:23.3vh;
height:15vh;
vertical-align:  middle;
list-style: none;
top:20px;
/* right: 10px;*/
right:10px;
/*margin-top:2px;*/
margin-left: 1vh;
margin-right:8vh;
text-decoration: none;
/* background-color: red;*/
display:table-cell;
background-color:  rgb(245, 239, 220);
text-align:center;

}
.rcontentdiv
{
width:23.3vh;
height:15vh;
list-style: none;
vertical-align:  middle;
top:20px;
right: 20px;
/* margin-top:1vh;*/
margin-left: 1vh;
margin-right: 2vh;
background-color:  beige;
text-align:  center;
display:table-cell;
text-decoration: none;
}




.arrowtab
{
width:10vh;
height:20vh;
background-color: aqua;
float:left;
}
.normtab
{
width:70vh;
height:20vh;
background-color:olive;
float:right;
}
.newRow
{
width:79.5vh;
background-color:  gray;
border-bottom: 1px;

border-bottom-color: black;
border-bottom-style: solid;
}
.hoverdiv
{
width:3vh;
height:5vh;
background-color:  beige;
border-width: 2px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: red;
float:left;

}


.leftsub
{
width:60px;
height:10px;
float: left;
border-width: 2px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: green;

}

.popup
{
width:150px;
height:40px;
float: right;
font-size: 12px;
text-align:  center;
position: relative;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
/*background-color: yellow;*/
display: none;
vertical-align: middle;
margin-right:30px;
/*line-height:  10%;*/
/*  border-width: 2px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: green; */
text-decoration: none;
list-style-type: none;

}
.popup:hover
{
width:150px;
height:40px;
float: right;
font-size: 12px;
text-align:  center;
position: relative;
/*background-color: yellow;*/
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
margin-right: 30px;
margin:0px;
bottom: 150px;
/*line-height:  10%;*/
text-decoration: none;
list-style-type: none;

padding:0px;

}
ul>li>a{
text-decoration: none;
color:white;
}

.imgdiv
{
margin-top: 50px;
margin-left: 13px;
width:20px;
height:20px;

}
.imgcol
{

width:20px;
height:20px;

}
.col1
{
width:35px;
height:39.5px;
text-align:  center;
line-height: 50%;
font-size: 12px;
vertical-align: middle;
display: table-cell;
background-color: black;
color:white;
border-right:1px solid white;
}

.col2
{
width:35px;
height:39.5px;
text-align:  center;
display: table-cell;
line-height: 50%;
font-size: 12px;
vertical-align: middle;
background-color: black;

color:white;
}
.col3
{
width:35px;
height:39.5px;
text-align:  center;
display: table-cell;

font-size: 12px;
vertical-align: middle;
background-color: black;
color:white;
border-left: 1px solid white;
margin-bottom: 50px;

}
.col4
{
width:20px;
height:20px;
margin-bottom: 3px;
margin-top: 8px;
text-align:  center;
display: table-cell;


}
```

Comment: You want the popup to show for all divs when you hover the first div or hover any div and show all popups? If any div, then just replace `$(this)` with `$(".imgdiv")`. Or are you saying you want the popup to show on the hovered div?

Comment: @Huangism any div i hover on should show its individual popup

Comment: On a side note, you have repeating IDs of `imgdiv`. IDs has to be unique

Comment: What does your code do right now?

Comment: right now say i have data one and two..it displays on both div one and div two, when i move the mouse over to div one the popup div will display on both div one and div two(even when i didnt mouseover div two). what i want is div one, on mouseover should display popup div for its self and div two for itself. not div one or div two doing it for both. thanks

Comment: Yea I get it, I already posted the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is you are using

```
$( ".popup" ).toggle('slow');
```

this will target all `.popup` so all of them will show/hide

**Given your current code**, you could do

`$(this).next().toggle('slow')` and `$(this).next().hide()`

Simplified example here https://jsfiddle.net/L85ksjr6/1/ I am using `.show()` because it is easier to show it. As for the image it is obviously missing due to the path, I put alt text in there, in Firefox I can see the alt text and hover to see the effects, in case you are having trouble with it

Answer (score 0):

You are using an element class as the selector for the mouseover. you need to use an element id.
A different jquery function must therfor be made for each div. this can be done systematiclly or manually. I recommend you start with manually.